# Lightroom 6 | Importing videos increases "Media Cache Files" folder size out of limits

Tags: lightroom

I recently installed Lightroom 6, I'm a new user. When I import all my photos (a folder 'Photos' with more than 50000 photos and videos) to my catalogue the folder C:\Users{myuser}\AppData\Local\Adobe\Lightroom\Caches\Video\Media Cache Files start to increase its size and I finish without space in my SSD Drive.

What can I do?
- Is it possible to disable the video cache?
- Or I will have to disable the video files import? How?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue with MKLINK

1) Close Lightroom

2) Move all content in folder "C:\Users{myuser}\AppData\Local\Adobe" to another folder in other HD. Not move the folder "Adobe", Just the content inside (sub folder and files).

3) Delete the folder "Adobe" in "C:\Users{myuser}\AppData\Local\".

4) Open a CMD as Administrator and type:

mklink /D C:\Users{myuser}\AppData\Local\Adobe F:\temp\Clon_Appdata_Local_Adobe

- mklink will create a symbolic link
- {myuser} must be your own user name in your Windows
- F:\temp\Clon_Appdata_Local_Adobe is the target folder where the files will exist really

This work for me.

Comment: So this doesn't solve the size occupied by the cache but at least you can free C:\ space, isn't it?